How to bound the total number of trials for a Binomial distribution if number of success is given?
Suppose I am sampling a random variable that follows a binomial distribution $Binomial(n, p)$. The sample rate $p$ is known. Now, after the sampling, I got $m$ success cases. How do I find the upper bound of $n$, with an error rate of $\alpha$? In other words, is it possible to calculate the probability of error given a certain $n$?
I believe inverse the lower bound of the Chernoff bound is supposed to be the bound I want to use: $\mathbb{P} [X \leq (1 - \delta)* n * p] \leq exp(-\frac{\delta^2 n p}{2})$. But I don't think it is safe to inverse the inequality directly.

If $X$ is Binomial($n,p$) and you want an upper bound for $n$, you can ask: how unilkely is it to get so small result as $m$ or below?
Hence you need to find the smallest $n$ such that
$$
\mathbb{P}_n(X\le m)=\sum_{k=0}^m \binom nk p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\le \alpha.
$$

Thanks a lot for your answer! I just realized that the problem is exactly the same as a negative binomial distribution, so it should be trivial to get the answer.
